Question about partial derivative of logarithm
Let $\Omega$ be an open set and $f \in H(\Omega)$. I want to compute
$\frac{\partial \log(f\overline{f})}{\partial \overline{z}}$.

What I've tried:

$\frac{\partial \log(f\overline{f})}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{\partial \log}{\partial z} \circ (f\overline{f}) \frac{\partial f \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}} + \frac{\partial \log}{\partial \overline{z}} \circ (f \overline{f}) \frac{\partial f\overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}}$. But because $log$ is a holomorphic branch of logarithm, then $\frac{\partial \log}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$, so $\frac{\partial \log(f\overline{f})}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{\partial \log}{\partial z} \circ (f \overline{f}) \frac{\partial f \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}}$. It's ok until there? That's all I want to know.

Why are you interpreting $f\bar{f}$ as $f\circ \bar{f}$ and not $|f|^2$ ?

@NinadMunshi woops. Sorry. It was a typo. Thanks for info. It's ok now?

Nothing is wrong here, I just think you're going to regret the notation. Either switch to partial operators like $\partial_z\log(f\bar{f})$ or if you are going to stay with the fraction notation actually write out the dependence symbolically like $$\frac{\partial\log(f\bar{f})}{\partial (f\bar{f})}$$

I 100% agree with you about the notation. Thanks for tips! :)
